# How inner join in Graphql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

I have some problem with my graph ql. I have a function to get value from DB. It have 2 field A and B

```
type A {
  id ID
  b [B]
}

Type B {
  id ID
  somedata String
}
```

My query is

```
mutation {
  type A (objID: 10167182) {
    id
    b (status: 1){
        id
        somedata
      }
  }
```

But the problem is that elements get returned which satisfy the filter on A but may have no element B. So the filters as a whole work like “outer joins”. what is the equivalent of an inner join?

Tks guys

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've asked this very precisely unfortunately as you basically are asking questions about your own code (?) which you then don't really explain.

If I understand this correctly you have two resolvers on two fields, one on `Mutation.a` (do make sure the notation of code you post is correct; the GraphQL SDL you've posted is invalid) and another on `A.b`. If I understand you correctly you are attempting to create a resolver on `A.b` that's limited to `A`.

This means that your resolver in `A.b` is ignoring which *parent* it's on and instead just implements itself as if it was on `Query.b`. Instead, you'll need to implement it manually in such a way that it uses its parent to limit the queries you run.

I haven't personally used `graphql-dotnet` myself, but every GraphQL implementation will typically define resolvers with four distinct arguments: parent, field arguments, info, and context. In this case you'll have to look for the *parent* argument and then use that to limit the queries you run.